# Dry baked goods

Tags: baking, bread

I've recently purchased new ovens and was excited to bake in them as the heating circulation was supposed to be superior and temperature more accurate.  Most of the baked goods in the new ovens are not as moist as previous goods, particularly items made with yeast dough but cookies seem to be drier as well.  Any ideas as to why this may be happening?

Answer (score 4):

Have you made any adjustments for the new ovens?

One thing is checking if the temperatures are the same as what's indicated (which is most helpful if you also checked that the temperatures on the OLD ovens were the same as indicated, or know how far and in what direction they were not.)

In addition, if you have moved from a "conventional" to a "convection" oven (which sounds like what you are describing) it is often necessary to compensate  for the *better heat circulation* by **shortening the cooking times** appropriately. Goods cook faster in a convection oven.

Comment: Yup, it does kind of sound like the old oven was undershooting temperatures, and the new one is more accurate and thus hotter.

Comment: Shortening cooking times yes, but another option is lowering the temperature

Answer (score 1):

Different oven designs are differently sealed, and keep a different level of humidity inside them; this is most obviously evident when opening the oven with your face near the oven door - some (very dry, well ventilated) will hardly do anything to you, others will burn your nose hair clean off (hot steam).